# How to increase chance to hit target?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

In Might & Magic X Legacy one of my group members is a dwarven defender.
But almost everytime (90%) he misses the target when trying to provoke it.

I'm not sure of the correct translation but it's one of the defenders first skills to provoke/taunt/challenge a single target in melee combat.

How do I increase the chance for him to hit the target? Is there a special attribute I should focus on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little late so you might know already. Still I'll answer if only for other viewers.

Yes there is a way.

- Take a look at the weapon skill. Every point spend will increase attack.
- Then there is the armor skill. Wearing armor gives a penalty to attack, but increasing the skill will decrease this penalty.
- And lastly Perception.  You could some spend points there.

Build option:

- At creation take Crossbow and Warfare, and put all points in Perception.
- At level ups divide the points into Might, Vitality and Perception, and focus on weapon/armor skill first.

Have fun !